# Isomorphism between an group and its double dual

Tags: representation-theory, characters

I wanted to prove that for an abelian group $G$ 
, $\phi : G \rightarrow \hat{\hat{G}}$ is an isomorphism  where $\hat{G}$ is a set of all irreducible characters of $G$

for $x \in G$, $[\phi(x)](\chi) = \chi(x)$.

My approach : I have already proved that $\vert \hat{G}\vert = \vert G \vert $
Now I thought its enough to say that for any $g \in G$ there exists an irreducible character $\chi$ such that $\chi(g) \neq 1 \forall g \in G$ and thus this map is injection. 
I dont know what next ..

Comment: Your approach seems fine (although for completeness you should verify that this map is actually a homomorphism).  For the last part try looking at the character of the regular representation.

Comment: can you please explain in a bit more detail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\chi_{reg}$ is the character of the regular representation, then we have $\chi_{reg}(g) = 0$ for all nontrivial $g \in G$. On the other hand, it is a positive integral combination of irreducible characters (in fact it is just the sum of all of them). In particular we can't have a positive integral combination of positive real numbers summing to 0, so for all nontrivial $g$ we can't have $\chi(g) = 1$ for all irreducible characters.